# Longneck Ascendant Rifle Very Expensive Craft

Tags: server-administration, ark-survival-evolved

I have a Nitrado server with my friends.

We wanted to make the ascendant rifles but it is asking us for 17160 metal ingots which cannot even fit in the slot spaces at the smithy table or anywhere else.

How do we change this?

Answer (score 1):

That will fit in a Tek Replicator which has 600 slots.